# Слайдер с ползунком на чистом js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по слайдеру с ползунком несколько вопросов.

https://codepen.io/Galtran/pen/YRWbqM?editors=0010

```
'use strict';

// slider.js

(function () {

  window.slider = function (bar, thumb) {

    // var output = document.querySelector('#output1');

    var moveThumb = function (evt) {
      var THUMB_WIDTH = thumb.offsetWidth;

      var LimitMovementX = {
        min: bar.offsetLeft,
        max: bar.offsetLeft + bar.offsetWidth - THUMB_WIDTH
      }

      var thumbCoord = thumb.offsetLeft + evt.movementX;
      // var value = thumbCoord * 100 / LimitMovementX.max ^ 0;

      if (thumbCoord < LimitMovementX.min) {
        thumbCoord = LimitMovementX.min;
      } else if (thumbCoord > LimitMovementX.max) {
        thumbCoord = LimitMovementX.max;
      }

      thumb.style.left = thumbCoord + 'px';
      // output.textContent = value;
    };

    var onThumbMousedown = function () {

      var onDocumentMousemove = function (evt) {
        moveThumb(evt);
      };

      var onThumbMouseup = function () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMousemove);
        thumb.removeEventListener('mouseup', onThumbMouseup);
      };

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMousemove);
      thumb.addEventListener('mouseup', onThumbMouseup);
    };

    thumb.addEventListener('mousedown', onThumbMousedown);
  };

}());

// main.js

(function () {

  var bar1 = document.querySelector('#bar1'),
    thumb1 = document.querySelector('#thumb1'),
    bar2 = document.querySelector('#bar2'),
    thumb2 = document.querySelector('#thumb2');

  window.slider(bar1, thumb1);
  window.slider(bar2, thumb2);

})();
```

1. В slider.js закомментированы 3 строчки. Они выводят положение в % от 0 до 100 на первый слайдер. Пока не знаю, как сделать, чтобы в main.js возвращалось значение(value) для каждого ползунка отдельно.
2. Иногда ползунок прилипает к курсору, даже когда кнопка мыши отпущена. "Отлипает" только после повторного нажатия на ползунок.

Comment: @АнатолийСоколову Вас изначально не совсем верный подход - через _id_ теряется гибкость и универсальность. Думаю, что в ответе будут максимально видны и понятны отличия и реализация.

Answer (score 2):

```js
'use strict';
// slider.js
(function() {
  window.slider = function(oSlider, nMin, nMax) {
    let bar = oSlider.querySelector('.slider__bar'),
      thumb = oSlider.querySelector('.slider__toggle'),
      output = oSlider.querySelector('.slider__output');
    output.textContent = nMin;
    let LimitMovementX, thumbCoord;

    function moveThumb(e) {
      LimitMovementX = {
        min: bar.offsetLeft,
        max: bar.offsetLeft + bar.offsetWidth - thumb.offsetWidth
      }
      thumbCoord = thumb.offsetLeft + e.movementX;

      if (thumbCoord < LimitMovementX.min) {
        thumbCoord = LimitMovementX.min;
      }
      if (thumbCoord > LimitMovementX.max) {
        thumbCoord = LimitMovementX.max;
      }
      output.textContent = nMin + thumbCoord * (nMax - nMin) / LimitMovementX.max ^ 0;
      thumb.style.left = thumbCoord + 'px';
    };

    function onThumbMouseup() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveThumb);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onThumbMouseup);
    };
    thumb.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      this.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveThumb);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', onThumbMouseup);
    });
  };
}());

// main.js
(function() {
  window.slider(document.querySelector('#slider1'), 1, 100);
  window.slider(document.querySelector('#slider2'), 2, 12);
})();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 0;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  user-select: none;
}

.slider__bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.slider__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider" id="slider1">
    <div class="slider__bar"></div>
    <div class="slider__toggle"></div>
    <p class="slider__content">Сумма: <span id="output1" class="slider__output"></span> млн. &#8381;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider" id="slider2">
    <div class="slider__bar"></div>
    <div class="slider__toggle"></div>
    <p class="slider__content">Срок: <span id="output2" class="slider__output"></span> мес.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```